# Covered problem for Schedule class

Tags: unit-test, schedulebatch

Maybe somebody has an idea why the test method doesn't cover. Uncovered method -

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Growtivity_CM__Zorgovereenkomst_Product__c> scope) {
```

Class

```
global class ScheduleUpdateRollUp implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {

    global final String query = 'SELECT Id, End_date__c , Start_date__c  ' +
            'FROM X_Product__c  ' +
            'where Start_date__c  <= TODAY ' +
            'and (End_date__c  >= TODAY or End_date__c  = Null)';

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        System.debug('Start');
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Product__c> scope) {
        System.debug('execute');
        List<Product__c> prod = new List<Product__c>();

for (Product__c prodItem : scope) {
            prodItem.IsActive__c = true;
            prod.add(prodItem);
        }
        update prod;
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {

    }

// implement Schedulable

//    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
////        System.debug('777execute(SchedulableContext sc)');
////        RollUpBatch ubc = new RollUpBatch();
////        System.schedule('Update RollUps', CRON_EXP, ubc);
//    }

}
```

Test

```
@isTest
private class ScheduleUpdateRollUpTest {
    @testSetup
    static void setup() {
        List<Product__c> prod = new List<Product__c>();
        for (Integer i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            prod.add(new Product__c(
                    Contract_name__c = 'Test',
                    Startdate__c = date.newInstance(2020, 10, 21)));
        }
        insert prod;

        Id parentId = [select id from Product__c limit 1].id;

        List<X_Product__c> x_prod = new List<X_Product__c>();
        for (Integer i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            x_prod.add(new Product__c(
                    Care_Contract__c = parentId,
                    IsActive__c = true));
        }
        insert x_prod;

    }
    @isTest
    static void scheduleTest() {
        Test.startTest();
        ScheduleUpdateRollUp sRollUp = new ScheduleUpdateRollUp();
        Id batchId = Database.executeBatch(sRollUp);
        Test.stopTest();
//        System.assertEquals(10, [
//                select count()
//                from Product__c
//                where IsActive__c = true]);
    }
}
```

Thank you a lot!

Comment: it looks like to example

Comment: You didn't mentioned what lines are not covered, I assume it is the execute. Suggest to debug and test your data, in many cases the test doesn't have data that apply to the query. + Also it is possible that you insert the data with some values, but other processes in the org changing the data during creation.

Comment: The batch looks broken... `execute` is declared as receiving Product__c records but `start` returns a query locator against X_Product__c.

Comment: @LironC Thank you. Yes, you are totally right. It's in execution.

Comment: @PhilW Thank you. I'll check

Comment: @All ... add few fields to query - this solve coverage. Pay attention to this (for next who will be faced with this issue)